# ModuleNotFoundError: Python 3.6 does not find modules while Python 3.5 does

Tags: import, python-3.6

I wanted to upgrade my python version from 3.5 to 3.6. Since I am using [WinPython](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winpython/), I have downloaded and installed the recent version just as I did it before with version 3.5.

However, if I use version 3.6 I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` whenever I import a self-created module. A minimal example: I created a file `t1.py` that contains only a `pass` statement and a file `t2.py` containing the following code:

```
import t1
print("done")
```

Both files are in the same folder `D:\MyProject\src`. Now when I run the file with python 3.5, everything works fine:

```
'C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2\python-3.5.1.amd64\python.exe' D:\MyProject\src\t2.py
done
```

However, with python 3.6 I get

```
'C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.6.0.1Qt5\python-3.6.0.amd64\python.exe' D:\MyProject\src\t2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\MyProject\src\t2.py", line 6, in <module>
    import t1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 't1'
```

I ran out of ideas what the issue could be and would appreciate new inspiration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Would this work ? in t2.py

```
import os
__path__=[os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))]
from . import t1
print("t2 done")
```

Python-3.6 changes its  way of working, with the "python._pth" file next to python.exe (instead of  "pyvenv.cfg" in previous versions)

If you don't want to modify your source, then you have to add "D:\MyProject\src" line in Python._pth file, or a relative path to it from python._pth location. in my example, it works with:

```
python36.zip
DLLs
Lib
.
..\test
import site
```

"http://bugs.python.org/issue29578?@ok_message=msg%20287921%20created%0Aissue%2029578%20message_count%2C%20messages%20edited%20ok&@template=item"

Other, simpler solution if you have no system-installed python: rename the "python._pth" file, next to "python.exe", as "pythonzz._pth"

The Python "Windows" maintainer just wrote that the simpler solution should be ok also with Python-3.6.0.

Comment: this is the test that worked on my pc, with t2.py launched via idle

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue29578?@ok_message=issue%2029578%20title%20edited%20ok&@template=item

Comment: update the initial answer, after looking at existing options in the 3.6 documentation

Comment: there may be a simple option, if you don't have any python as a system install: rename the file "python._pth" next to python.exe as "zpython._pth"

Comment: I intend to use (and register) the WinPython3.6 version as my standard python interpreter. Therefore, renaming the python._pth file is the way to go for me, and it worked. I do not want to use the rather messy new import statements.

Comment: This is what worked for me too.