# Distutils do not call "link.exe" when using WinPython 3.6, but with WinPython 3.5 it works

Tags: compilation, distutils, python-c-extension, python-3.6

I recently upgraded from [Winpython](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winpython/) version 3.5 to the respective version with python 3.6. Therefore, I have to recompile my C extensions using the new interpreter. My setup script looks as follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
import numpy.distutils.misc_util

c_ext = Extension("heapoperations", ["heapoperations.c"])

setup(
    ext_modules=[c_ext],
    include_dirs=numpy.distutils.misc_util.get_numpy_include_dirs(),
)
```

The console output when using python 3.5 was

```
running build_ext
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
building 'heapoperations' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I"C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -I"C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2\python-3.5.1.amd64\include" -I"C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2\python-3.5.1.amd64\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\winrt" /Tcheapoperations.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\heapoperations.obj
Found executable C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2\python-3.5.1.amd64\libs" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2\python-3.5.1.amd64\PCbuild\amd64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_heapoperations build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\heapoperations.obj /OUT:D:\MyProject\heapoperations.cp35-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\heapoperations.cp35-win_amd64.lib
Found executable C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\link.exe
```

However, when I run the same script with python 3.6 I get

```
running build_ext
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
building 'heapoperations' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I"C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.6.0.1Qt5\python-3.6.0.amd64\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -I"C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.6.0.1Qt5\python-3.6.0.amd64\include" -I"C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.6.0.1Qt5\python-3.6.0.amd64\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\winrt" /Tcheapoperations.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\heapoperations.obj
Found executable C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe
```

That is, `link.exe` is not called. The result is that I do not get a `.pyd` file that allows me to use the code.

What could explain the behaviour? How could I make everything work under WinPython 3.6?

I am using 64bit WinPython under Windows 10 64bit.

Comment: probably not the answer, but re-try after having renamed python._pth, a file next to python.exe,  as python_nomore._pth

Comment: @stonebig I have done this already. It has no effect on the issue. I am aware of your answer to my previous issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263962/modulenotfounderror-python-3-6-does-not-find-modules-while-python-3-5-does/42266369?noredirect=1#comment71720852_42266369

Comment: ok, another stupid idea is that there is a border effect with previously compiled with python-3.5 objects... maybe try to change names of your files to be sure to have no "prior" objects on your system ?

Comment: @stonebig: Unfortunately, renaming did not make a difference.

Comment: I am out of idea then.. you are not using Qt4 in your extension, do you ?

Comment: @stonebig: No, I am not using Qt4. I also do not think that the issue has anything to do with my code, because I do not get an error message. Distutils is just behaving weirdly...

Comment: well, just in case, launch "script\make_cython_use_vc.bat".

Answer (score 0):

I did a try from http://dan.iel.fm/posts/python-c-extensions/ 
(and _chi2.c from https://gist.github.com/douglas-larocca/099bf7460d853abb7c17)

result:

```
C:\WinPython\basedir36\buildQt5\winpython-64bit-3.6.x.2\notebooks>python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
building '_chi2' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\WinPython\basedir36\buildQt5\winpython-64bit-3.6.x.2\python-3.6.0.amd64\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\WinPython\basedir36\buildQt5\winpython-64bit-3.6.x.2\python-3.6.0.amd64\include -IC:\WinPython\basedir36\buildQt5\winpython-64bit-3.6.x.2\python-3.6.0.amd64\include -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tc_chi2.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_chi2.obj
Found executable C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\WinPython\basedir36\buildQt5\winpython-64bit-3.6.x.2\python-3.6.0.amd64\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\WinPython\basedir36\buildQt5\winpython-64bit-3.6.x.2\python-3.6.0.amd64\include -IC:\WinPython\basedir36\buildQt5\winpython-64bit-3.6.x.2\python-3.6.0.amd64\include -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tcchi2.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\chi2.obj
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\WinPython\basedir36\buildQt5\winpython-64bit-3.6.x.2\python-3.6.0.amd64\libs /LIBPATH:C:\WinPython\basedir36\buildQt5\winpython-64bit-3.6.x.2\python-3.6.0.amd64\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit__chi2 build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_chi2.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\chi2.obj /OUT:C:\WinPython\basedir36\buildQt5\winpython-64bit-3.6.x.2\notebooks\_chi2.cp36-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_chi2.cp36-win_amd64.lib
Found executable C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\link.exe

C:\WinPython\basedir36\buildQt5\winpython-64bit-3.6.x.2\notebooks>
```

test of result:

```
PS C:\WinPython\basedir36\buildQt5\winpython-64bit-3.6.x.2\notebooks> python
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import _chi2; print (_chi2.chi2(2.0, 1.0, [-1.0, 4.2, 30.6], [-1.5, 8.0, 63.0], [1.0, 1.5, 0.6]))
2.8988888888888766
```